# How to solve "no space left" on device error on GCP

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-shell

What could be causing the 'failed to register layer: write /usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/nvidia/cusparse/lib/libcusparse.so.12: no space left on device' error when trying to pull a 5.76GB Docker image into GCP Cloud Shell?

The error occurs after the image download is complete and is being extracted.

Comment: Err, free some space? Buy more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google Cloud Shell only provides 5 GB of working space. The error message means you have run out of free space to store the object. Cloud Shell does not allow you to increase the disk storage space.

If you need more than 5 GB, I recommend launching a Compute Engine instance for your work.

> Cloud Shell provisions 5 GB of free persistent disk storage mounted as
> your $HOME directory on the virtual machine instance.

[How Cloud Shell works](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/how-cloud-shell-works)

Comment: Thank you for this. I created a VM instance and tried to pull the same image into the vm and i got the same issue.

Comment: @B.obed - Most likely you did not modify the boot disk size to be large enough for your work.

Comment: The book disk size here is 10GB and the image is approximately 6GB. Is there something i might be missing?

Comment: @B.obed 10 GB is probably not enough to unpack a 6 GB image. Create a VM with a 30+ GB disk drive. Tip: 10 GB is tiny today.